# graphical timeline create software API for profiling a multithreaded C++ program

Tags: c++, multithreading, profiling

I am building a high performance multi-threaded program. Durations of some functions and the overlapping of execution count a lot and I wish to somehow produce a kind of a visual timeline graph showing at what time functions began and their durations. I wish for something similar to the graphs of the NVIDIA profiler. Using the `boost::chrono` package I already collect timelines, but can't find any software or API that plots them out. Does anybody knows of any?

Regards

Daniel

Comment: what runtime platform do you use?

Comment: If you know opengl already (as you seem to), why not using that for your rendering? If your programme is CPU bound, that solution should not incur much overhead to your programme.

Comment: @yohjp... sorry forgot to say that I am using C++ on linux.. but I wish to keep code compatibility as to compile also on windows in due time

Comment: @didierc .. I use NVIDIA GPUs for HPC..I neither use OpenGL nor OpenCL  , but CUDA, but is it easy to learn openGL?

Comment: The way I understood your question, you wanted to watch the graph in realtime, hence my suggestion of OpenGL. I don't know OpenCL nor cuda, so it's difficult for me to tell whether it's going to be hard to learn OpenGL. However, thinking about it, even if it turns out easy thanks to your knowledge of cuda, implementing the display will probably not be trivial. What sort of graphics do you have in mind exactly?

Comment: I was thinking about a horizontal axis for time flow, with function calls stacking up as duration lines, and each thread having its own horizontal slice of the screen, but after seeing the qvalgrind screenshots, I wondered if you weren't thinking about real call trees.Besides, if your app is doing of thousands of function calls per sec., my idea isn't very realistic. So it really depends on what you are actually logging.

Comment: @didierc .. No real time creating of graphics, the system generates all the statistics (for example a load from hardisk took 1s and happened between the 1st second and 2nd second of program execution), then I create charts offline or at the end of the program. The idea you expressed in the last comment is exactly what I want..I was not thinking about call trees

Comment: Well, if that's what you want, I suppose that it's doable in OpenGL without too much difficulty. The first part will be to organize your data in such a way that you can select the events, call stacks, etc. that happens between two given timestamps (the left and right limits of your rendering window). The second part is drawing specifically, which can be done using OpenGL, or more simply with any 2D drawing library, since it will be offline rendering. The hardest part will be the first one I reckon. The second one will be mostly about learning the API, no huge stopgap there imho.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [kcachegrind](http://kcachegrind.sourceforge.net/html/Home.html), I think it does what you want. Here are some [screenshots](http://kcachegrind.sourceforge.net/html/Screenshots.html).

If you don't want to use callgrind and you would rather generate the graphs yourself, consider using [Graphviz](http://www.graphviz.org/). All you need to do to produce a graph with graphviz is to create a description of the graph in a simple text format.

Comment: Having alook, but of the records I need asolution that works evn for release, ie no -g option but rather -O3.. kcachegrind works only with -g isn't it?

Comment: I think all valgrind tools are indifferent to `-g`. Note that you can compile with `-O3` and `-g` at the same time.

Comment: OK, not exactly (from http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/quick-start.html): 'Compile your program with -g to include debugging information so that Memcheck's error messages include exact line numbers.'. But in general it can still work without -g. Of course, with `-O3` and agresive inlining the information you get can be imprecise.

Answer (score -1):

If you have "Microsoft Visual Studio 2012 Professional (or higher Ed.)" and run program on Windows, [Concurrency Visualizer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537632.aspx) may be useful. This tool can profile and visualize thread/cpu utilization on timeline for even C++ application.

see also [MSDN Blogs](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualizeparallel/archive/2011/09/19/how-can-visual-studio-11-developer-preview-visualize-the-behavior-of-a-multithreaded-application.aspx).